# How do I create an ms-access macro that will RUN a make table query? (not just open it)

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

I am trying to create a macro in access 2013 that RUNS a make table query. As far as I can tell, using the macro action 'OpenQuery' is the most obvious action that could do this. However, this literally opens the query and doesn't create an actual physical table.

How do I make this macro RUN the make table query to create a new table?

Comment: runsql I think from docmd or currentproject.connection.execute

Comment: http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/RunSQL_vs_Execute

Comment: does this have to be done with code or is there a way to do it with built in macro actions?

Answer (score 0):

Running a make table query from the DB object list is the same as `DoCmd.OpenQuery "make table query"` in VBA, and the same as running a macro with the macro action 'OpenQuery'.

In all cases the table is created (after showing warnings about creating the table).

So either you picked the wrong query, or it isn't actually a make table query (SELECT INTO).

Comment: This did not answer the question. It's a make table query (its the only query in the database) and is the correct one. When you use the macro action 'OpenQuery' it does not make a table it opens it as if it were a select query. When I physically click run on the query design itself it does create a table.

Comment: Please add the Access version tag to your question. Access 2010 behaves as I described. @mattyb

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved your issue, but Andre's answer is correct, you just have to make sure that you save your query once you make it as a "Make table" query. It should show in your object list with an exclamation mark to indicate it will update data.